# Java 9 third-party module « linking », how?, when? -> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, module

Please do not provide solutions using Maven, Gradle… I look for a CLI solution **only**. No jlink-based solution as well.

Given `Open_My_type_module-1.0.jar` as a **preexisting** compiled Java 9 module:

```
module Open_My_type_module { // module-info.java
    exports Open_My_type_package;
    opens Open_My_type_package;
}
```

The code in this module only declares the following class:

> Open_My_type_package.My_type

I reuse this module into another one as follows:

```
module Access_My_type_module { // module-info.java
    requires Open_My_type_module;
}
```

// Business code (for test only in a *Main.java* class):

```
Class<Open_My_type_package.My_type> c = Open_My_type_package.My_type.class;
```

Starting from the following structure:

```
THIRD_PARTY_MODULE >> Open_My_type_module-1.0.jar
src >> main >> java >> com >> X >> Access_My_type_package >> Main.java
src >> main >> java >> module-info.java
```

Compilation **succeeds** based the following line:

```
javac -d PRODUCTION_SOFTWARE --module-path THIRD_PARTY_MODULE src/main/java/com/X/Access_My_type_package/Main.java src/main/java/module-info.java
```

Next, before execution, I package my software as follows:

```
cd PRODUCTION_SOFTWARE
jar --create --verbose --file Access_My_type_module-1.0.jar --main-class com.X.Access_My_type_package.Main *
```

Packaging *DOES NOT* seem to « link » *Open_My_type_module-1.0.jar* in the final executable, but I check the inside of the packaged software:

```
jar --file=Access_My_type_module-1.0.jar --describe-module
```

Display (everything seems sound):

```
Access_My_type_module jar:file://./Access_My_type_module-1.0.jar/!module-info.class
requires Open_My_type_module
requires java.base mandated
contains com.X.Access_My_type_package
main-class com.X.Access_My_type_package.Main
```

Finally, execution fails with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` from:

```
java --module-path THIRD_PARTY_MODULE -jar Access_My_type_module-1.0.jar
```

I believed that `--module-path THIRD_PARTY_MODULE` is enough to link *Open_My_type_module-1.0.jar* at execution time, but I keep the feeling that my packaging command is shaky. Beyond, I’m sure I’ve missed of a key issue about Java 9 modules… HELP WELCOME please!

Answer (score 0):

Solution (below) is inspired from https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes/posts/guidetojava9-compilejarrun.

With Java modules, execution is better controlled using `--module` instead of `-jar`. So
`java --module-path THIRD_PARTY_MODULE --module Access_My_type_module` works fine!
Assumption: `Access_My_type_module-1.0.jar` must be located within `THIRD_PARTY_MODULE` along with `Open_My_type_module-1.0.jar` (for simplicity here). In short, `java` finds in the `THIRD_PARTY_MODULE` directory all the desired stuff.
Please note that `--module` required the module name (ie, `Access_My_type_module`) and
*NOT* the jar file name!
Please also note that `Access_My_type_module-1.0.jar` manifest has already been set up with a main class at packaging time... if not tell `java` which is the main class at execution time.